# Car moved to front when the engine is off while in D gear

Tags: brakes, automatic-transmission, suzuki, parking

I have a Suzuki Stingray 2014 vehicle and I am still new to it. Yesterday when I parked the vehicle on a cement floor, accidentally I had forgot to move the gear to the parking mode. However, I had turned the engine off. (I know that the key can't be taken out if the car is not in the parking mode. But this vehicle does not have a key. It functions with push start.)

Then all of a sudden I realized that the vehicle started to move to the front slowly. Luckily I was able apply the brakes and put the car into parking since I was still inside.

One other thing I must mention here is, I noted a strange sound when turning the steering wheel while the brakes applied (when reversing). However, I didn’t notice anything other than that with regards to brakes.

Is there any connection between car moving forward while the engine is off and the sound I mentioned? 
Is there anything wrong with the brakes, so that it causes the car to move?

What would be the actions I should take?

Comment: Does this car have an automatic emergency brake (hand brake)?  If not, had you pulled the brake on before it moved?

Comment: Was the vehicle on any kind of decline? The only way for the vehicle to move is if there's some force being applied to it. If the engine isn't on, the only other thing which might cause it to move (barring someone running into it) is if it's on a slope. Even a very slight slope is enough to get a car moving. May be it just started to roll on its own, since you didn't have the brakes applied and the vehicle wasn't in park.

Comment: thank you very much for your responses. I think there must have been at least of a slightest of declines where i parked. I didn't notice any move of the vehicle in other places I parked after that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since vehicle is in drive, it could easily move if it was on some kind of slope. I'm pretty sure you can't damage your car if it moved a bit, so don't worry everything is fine with your car. The sound you heard is most likely brakes squeezing. Maybe you had emergency brake on or applied some brakes to stop/slow and heard it.

Comment: thank you very much for your responses. I think there must have been at least of a slightest of declines where i parked. I didn't notice any move of the vehicle in other places I parked after that. :)

Comment: No problem I'm glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

When the engine is off the torque converter is "empty" ( no connection between the engine and transmission) so and any gear in the auto transmission is essentially neutral , except park.  Park will have some mechanical lock on the output shaft.